# Is there a real-valued function $f$ such that $f(f(x)) = -x$?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, functional-equations

Is there a function $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to\mathbb{R} $ such that $ f(f(x)) = -x$ ?

Comment: Answer to a generalization of this question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/71836/6179).

Comment: An [answer on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17614/solving-ffxgx/17621#17621) demonstrating that there is no such *continuous* $f$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is.

Let $\{A,B\}$ be a partition of the positive reals such that $|A|=|B|=|\mathbb{R}|$, and let $\varphi:A\to B$ be a bijection. Define $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ as follows:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }x=0\\
\varphi(x),&\text{if }x\in A\\
-\varphi^{-1}(x),&\text{if }x\in B\\
-\varphi(-x),&\text{if }-x\in A\\
\varphi^{-1}(-x),&\text{if }-x\in B\;.
\end{cases}$$

Then

$$\begin{align*}
f(f(x))&=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }x=0\\
f(\varphi(x)),&\text{if }x\in A\\
f(-\varphi^{-1}(x)),&\text{if }x\in B\\
f(-\varphi(-x)),&\text{if }-x\in A\\
f(\varphi^{-1}(-x)),&\text{if }-x\in B\;.
\end{cases}\\\\
&=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }x=0\\
-\varphi^{-1}(\varphi(x)),&\text{if }x\in A\\
-\varphi(\varphi^{-1}(x)),&\text{if }x\in B\\
\varphi^{-1}(\varphi(-x)),&\text{if }-x\in A\\
\varphi(\varphi^{-1}(-x)),&\text{if }-x\in B
\end{cases}\\\\
&=-x\;.
\end{align*}$$

The idea is simply that $f$ permutes the sets $A,B,-A$, and $-B$ in the order

$$A\stackrel{f}\longrightarrow B\stackrel{f}\longrightarrow -A\stackrel{f}\longrightarrow -B\stackrel{f}\longrightarrow A$$

while leaving $0$ fixed. (Here $-A= \{-a:a\in A\}$, and similarly for $-B$.)

**Added:** It is possible, though a bit messy, to define $A,B$ and $\varphi$ explicitly. We may, for example, set $A=(0,1]$ and $B=(1,\to)$ and define $\varphi$ as follows. First, for $n\in\omega$ let $\varphi(2^{-n})=2^{n+1}$, so that $\varphi(1)=2,\varphi(1/2)=4,\varphi(1/4)=8$, and so on. Then let $\varphi$ map the interval $(2^{-(n+1)},2^{-n})$ to the interval $(2^n,2^{n+1})$ in the obvious way, taking $x$ to $1/x$.

Comment: Your addendum looks very much like what is done in the post I mentioned.

Comment: @Didier: I’ve not yet had a chance to look at that one. I was just trying to find a simple, explicit bijection between a half-closed and an open interval.

Comment: More accurately, the idea on the page I referred you to (and here) is to exchange infinitely many disjoint intervals in a bijective way.